# For what value of $x$ is this matrix invertible?

Tags: matrices

I've been given the following matrix $X$:
$$X=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 8 & 1 \\     
0 & 30 &1  &  0 \\    
0 &2&  0&  0 \\     
1 &2 & 9 & x \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and I have to determine for which value of $x$ the matrix is invertible.
Any hints/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

So far I have substituted different values for $x$, but there seems to be an inverse for all values of $x$ above $1$.

Comment: Hint: a matrix is invertible whenever its determinant is non-zero.

Comment: If you have studied linear algebra, another hint: $X$ is invertible iff its columns are linearly independent.

Comment: A third hint:  If you use row operations to reduce the matrix to an upper or lower triangular matrix, then the determinant will just be the product of the main diagonal, then you will get invertible iff that product is nonzero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$X=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 8 & 1 \\     
0 & 30 &1  &  0 \\    
0 &2&  0&  0 \\     
1 &2 & 9 & x \\
\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{ R_4-R_1}\longrightarrow\;\; 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 8 & 1 \\     
0 & 30 &1  &  0 \\    
0 &2&  0&  0 \\     
0 &\!\!-2 & 1 & x-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-\frac1{15}R_2}{\stackrel{R_4+\frac1{15}R_2\;,\;R_2}\longrightarrow}
$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 8 & 1 \\     
0 & 30 &1  &  0 \\    
0 &0& \!\! -\frac1{15}&  0 \\     
0 &0 & \frac{16}{15} & x-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_4+16R_3}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 8 & 1 \\     
0 & 30 &1  &  0 \\    
0 &0& \!\! -\frac1{15}&  0 \\     
0 &0 & 0 & x-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and the above matrix (and thus the original one as well) is singular iff the last row is all zeros, so...

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You may use the well-known relation:
$$
\operatorname{tr}(X) = \log\Big(\det\big(\exp(X)\big)\Big)
$$